# wxLaunchDefaultBrowser doesn't work in snap-installed app

Tags: browser, snap

When I use the following wxWidgets API call...

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga3ff36fe489da2a779248b56f283615ca

...I get the following error...

"Failed to open URL "url goes here" in default browser. (error 11: Resource temporarily unavailable)"

...but only if I run my application as an installed snap.  It works fine during development.

Admittedly, I'm asking before I try to dig, but if I were to dig on this problem, I guess I would start by looking at the GTK2 implementation of the API call in wxWidgets to see what exactly it's trying to do.  From there I may be able to hypothesize about why it's not able to do it within the confined ubuntu-core environment.  So I'll try that, but in the mean time, does anyone that is familiar with the snap technology have an idea as to what might be going on?  Thanks in advance for any help.

I suppose this error isn't too surprising as a confined app is supposed to be running in a secure environment.  How do I make an exception in this case?

Comment: Additional info on this: I guess "Debug: Failed to connect to session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported."  So there's a clue.

Comment: Looking at the wxWidgets code, this comes down to a wxExecute call, which just shells out to some other program, in my case, the browser.  It's possible that snap-apps (I don't know what else to call them) are prevented from doing this kind of thing for security reasons.

Comment: I think this may be a problem where a snap-installed app can't call fork() and may be getting the EAGAIN error.  If my process was running as root, then it probably wouldn't have a problem.  I may be hitting the NPROC limit which may be set to 1 for all snap-installed apps for security reasons?

Comment: I thought for sure if I used the "process-control" interface that this would solve the problem.  No go there...  :(

Comment: My current theory is that I'm invoking the browser just fine, but when the browser tries to connect to the X-server, it's denied, because it's being run as a user other than me.  Whatever the snap black-magic is that bootstraps my own application would need to be applied to the browser too.